# Не работают стили

Tags: html, css

При задании цвета кнопке - синий, кнопка не меняет цвет, класс в моём случае b1

```
  .b1 {
  background: navy; /* Синий цвет фона */ 
  color: white; /* Белые буквы */ 
  font-size: 12pt; /* Размер шрифта в пунктах */
   }

<input type="button" name="button" class="b1" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
```

Comment: А где функция `areaRectangle` ?

Comment: она относилась не к теме

Answer (score 2):

Стили должны быть обернуты в тег `style`, либо загружены с помощью

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="linkto.css">
```

```html
<style>
.b1 {
  background: navy; /* Синий цвет фона */ 
  color: white; /* Белые буквы */ 
  font-size: 12pt; /* Размер шрифта в пунктах */
}
</style>

<input type="button" name="button" class="b1" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle();">
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало правильно